# Sunspot autocomplete plugin not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I plan on running my application using Heroku, Sunspot and WebSolr and need an autosuggest capabilities? Is there tutorials out there which help you with this? What is everyone using for autocomplete or autosuggestion when it comes to Sunspot?

Comment: Did you restart your server after installing the plugin? that field is defined in the plugin, and the plugin is sending it to ActionView, so it looks good.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, but now I have a different issue with the field, take a look above. Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
<%= autosuggest_text_field("product", "name", "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/", "product_name").html_safe %>
```

(it has .html_safe at the end)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Going to see if their are any different solutions available also.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was not able to get this to work either. The JSON response always returned 0 results.

Comment: @Maletor go ahead and open a question about it.... Since JSON is returning 0 questions, it's likely more a server problem (or a need to reindex) than this plugin's fault.